# How do I keep login an account after the first-time login?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a login system using PHP. So, How do I keep login an account after the first-time login?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have a look at [PHP Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) in their documentation.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to say for sure what you're having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies or sessions.

Session refrences:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Cookie refrences:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Cookies stay saved until the user clears them manually, or you make it expire. So that might be your best bet.

Do note that it's not safe to never log out your user. Make them log in every once in a while.